# Derivative of $\sin_dx$ when x is measured in degree

Tags: derivatives

Find the derivative of $\sin_d x,$ if $\sin_d x$ is the sine of $x$ where $x$ is taken to be in degrees.

please help me out solving this math question

Comment: @ Lakeside Swagger What are you differentiating it with? If you are differentiating it wrt x in degrees you will get cos x itself as the answer.

Comment: I feel like a more appropriate notation would be $\sin x°$ where $x$ is a plain number or $\sin x_d$ where $x_d=x°$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\sin_dx=\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{180}\right)$$